# Wrong line space when using babel, setspace & footmisc

Tags: spacing, footnotes, babel, line-spacing

I am trying to obtain 1.5 line space in footnotes but I obtain different result with and without `babel`. Without `babel` the output is ok but not when I activate it.

Maybe I use a wrong mix of packages. The chosen packages (not all are presented in the MWE) is specifically used for obtaining, 1.5 line space in the main part of the text, 1 line space in some parts (in quotations) and 1.5 in footnotes.

**MWE:**

```
   \documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
    %\usepackage[main=french,ngerman,english]{babel}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\setstretch{1.5}}% Footnotes are 
    \setstretch{1.5}
    \setlength{\footnotemargin}{2mm}

    \begin{document}

    \onehalfspace
    \lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum[1]}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `french` modul changes the layout of footnotes, and so `\footnotelayout` no longer does anything. But you still can use the switch `footmisc` adds for setspace:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}

    \usepackage[main=french,ngerman,english]{babel}
    %\frenchsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false} %alternative
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage[hang]{footmisc}     
    \makeatletter \FN@setspacefalse\makeatother

    \usepackage{lipsum}

    \setstretch{1.5}
    \setlength{\footnotemargin}{2mm}

 \begin{document}


    \lipsum*[1] \footnote{\lipsum[1]}
 \end{document}
```

An alternative is to disable the `FrenchFootnotes`.

Side remark: `onehalfspace` is an environment, don't use it as a command. You will get a non-closed group warning with it. The command name is `\onehalfspacing`.

Comment: Thank you for your help and your remark concerning `onehalfspace`. Another solution of my problem could be `\def\FN@baselinestretch{1.5}`